# Is it possible to map hosts instead of ports in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose up -d` to develop react apps.

However, since I'm developing many modules and apps, ports get really really confusing.

It's an old computer rule that:

**numbers are for computers, texts are for humans**

I wonder if it's possible to bind `host` to docker-compose instead of ports?

For example I would rather go to `app.local` instead of `localhost:3000`.

This way I can easily navigate between apps as I would remember their names very easily:

`app.local`
`module.local`
`admin.app.local`
`investor.app.local`
...

Comment: Since localhost reserves the entire subnet 127.0.0.0/8 (16,777,213 possibles), you should be able to exploit this property by binding different docker-compose apps to different addresses in that space. You might need to create a large number of loopback devices

Comment: the `.local` domain is for different stuff though. That is used by zeroconf to advertise services within your LAN

Comment: @code_monk, how should I do that? How can I **bind different docker-compose apps to different addresses in that space**? Also `.local` is what we use internally for development.

Comment: read this https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks